# I send a post request by scrapy, response data is 'too frequently',but i send this same request by postman,response is this i want

Tags: scrapy, postman

**
This is my code of my scrapy. I also send same request with postman.No matter i send it any times,i can recive data that i want.But i send it by scrapy,I recive data alwanys is 'too frequently,forbid visit'.Maybe there will are many causes.But I want to know what are the possible causes.
**

'

```
 class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['www.lagou.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.lagou.com/jobs/positionAjax.json?px=default&city=%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC&needAddtionalResult=false']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield FormRequest(
            self.start_urls[0],
            callback=self.parse,
        )

    def parse(self,response):
        print(response.text)
```

'

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the website that you are an actual user, not a bot

try sending a user-agent in the header

```
yield FormRequest(
            url=self.start_urls[0],
            callback=self.parse,
            headers={ 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36',}
        )
```